# how to update Normalize table USING GRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two normalized tables with the name `Division` and `Department`.

`Division` contain column {`DivisionId and DivisionName`} and `Department` contain {`DepartmentId,DepartmentName and DevisionId`}.

I need to update `Department` Table using gridview. how i can do it ? because when i give data source for the gridview, i can't give `DivisionName` due to `DevisionId` is found in the table department. does any one have such experience please ?

Please help me whether in coding or hint how can I update normalized table using gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `INNER JOIN` for this purpose.

```
Select Division.*, Department.* from Department Inner Join Division on Division.DivisionId=Department.DivisionId
```